# How do I find out how big is a community for example a web framework. 

Tags: python, web-frameworks

Are there tools which can do that for me? For example I want to compare how big a community is for a web framework in Python. And for my dimploma thesis is interesting to know, how big a community is and trends for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good indicator is the project's mailing list activity and number of subscribers. For example:

- http://groups.google.com/group/turbogears/about
- http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/about
- http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/about

Google Trends can also be helpful:

http://www.google.es/trends?q=pylons,+django,+turbogears

Comment: Considering how google trends works, I'm not sure that's really valid in this case. (Take a look at the links it's pointing you to)

Comment: A better Trends link: http://www.google.es/trends?q=django+python%2C+pylons+python%2C+turbogears+python%2C+repoze.bfg%2C+pyramid+python&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0

Answer (score 6):

I guess you won't find any "magic tools" for this purpose. Personally I would browse the web for a couple of hours and ask myself things such as:

- Are there any "official" communities/forums out there? Do they contain lots of documentation, references, videos, tutorials etc?
- Is the SDK recently updated? Are there good information about features in future SDK's etc?
- Are there many third-party/open source add-ons/extensions/framework out there?
- Does the forums has a lot of visitors and questions/answers?
- Take a look here at StackOverflow as well, how many questions are for example tagged with "Python". Are they recent?

Answering those questions might give a rather good indication of how big and "alive" a specific community is.

Maybe not the answer you were looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to look up the official support channels -- IRC, email, and forums -- and compare activity levels there.  You might also want to look at the liveliness of a package:  how frequent are its releases?  Has it had an alpha out for months with no sign of an update?  Are there books?

In the case of Python web frameworks, the big ones are [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) and (more of a CMS) [Plone](http://www.plone.org).  Both are mature, relatively stable projects with large followings.  After that, you're in a mess.  Pylons, repoze.bfg, and TurboGears recently merged into one umbrella, the [Pyramid project](http://docs.pylonshq.com/pyramid/dev/), which makes that project the front-runner to challenge Django's dominance in the Python "framework" world.

Unfortunately, you can also read that in another way:  Pylons and TurboGears admitted that their projects' respective approaches weren't working particularly well and shifted focus to helping develop repoze.bfg.  That might be great, but it also means that the platform is very much a moving target and probably not ready for prime time.  When assessing "activity," this sort of analysis is also important:  Pyramid looks more lively than any of its predecessors, but that may not be an indication that its activity is productive.